# Query Syntax Confusion

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a bit of confusion with my syntax here for this piece of code I am writing using VB inside Access DB.

```
Public Sub ()

 Dim dbs As DAO.Database
 Dim TrainingID As Integer
 Dim EmployeeIDTb1 As Integer
 Dim JobIDTb1 As Integer
 Dim CompetencyTb1 As String
 Dim DateApprovedTb1 As String
 Dim InsertStr As String

 TrainingID = 100


 Set dbs = CurrentDb
 Set dbs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1")

 'Do Until dbs1.Fields("ID").Value <> Null
 'set values
  EmployeeIDTbl1 = dbs1.Fields("EmployeeID").Value
 'JobIDTb1 = dbs1.Fields("JobID").Value
 'CompetencyTb1 = dbs1.Fields("Competency").Value
 'DateApprovedTb1 = dbs1.Fields("DateApproved").Value
 'Set Insert String
  InsertStr = "INSERT INTO TrainingList (EmployeeID.[Value]) Values(1) Where TrainingID = TrainingID;"

  dbs.Execute InsertStr
  TrainingID = TrainingID + 1
  'dbs1.MoveNext
  'Loop


 dbs.Close
 Set dbs = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Basically the Line Where I am confused is here.

```
InsertStr = "INSERT INTO TrainingList (EmployeeID.[Value]) Values(1) Where TrainingID = TrainingID;"
```

I'm trying to pass `EmployeeIDTbl1` into `Value(EmployeeIDTbl1)` as a parameter but I cant see to figure out what syntax is to fit inside there. Note `EmployeeIDTbl1` Returns a value = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the the solution I coded to deal with inserting records with Access 2013 for Multiple Value Fields In SharePoint.

First Step:

Create a local table that has the same Column Names as the SharePoint List.
(For this Code lets say its called "Table1")

Second Step: Import the data using an Excel into the created table.

Third Step: Count the amount of records in table.

Forth Step: Execute InitializeRecords Function

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub InitalizeRecords()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim BufferVal As Integer
Dim RecordSize As Integer


Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set dbs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM 'The Table You're Using'")

'Intialize Variables'
BufferVal = 1
RecordSize = 'Enter Amount of Records to be Inserted'

For i = 1 To RecordSize
'Insert Buffer Records'
 dbs2.AddNew
 dbs2("Title").Value = BufferVal
 BufferVal = BufferVal + 1
 dbs2.Update
 Next



End Sub
```

This function Initializes the table and Inserts empty records into the Table in Share Point to populate the Primary Key values, In this example "TrainingID"

Step 5: Execute InsertRecords Function

```
Dim DateApprovedTbl1 As String
Dim InsertStr As String
Dim InsertStr2 As String
Dim InsertStr3 As String
Dim InsertStr4 As String
Dim BufferVal As Integer
Dim MaxRecords As Integer

 Set dbs = CurrentDb
 Set dbs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1")
 Set dbs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TrainingList")


'Intialize Training ID Value'
 TrainingID = dbs2.Fields("TrainingID").Value


Do Until dbs1.Fields("ID") <> Null

   'set values'
    EmployeeIDTbl1 = dbs1.Fields("EmployeeID").Value
    JobIDTbl1 = dbs1.Fields("JobID").Value
    CompetencyTbl1 = dbs1.Fields("Competency").Value
    DateApprovedTbl1 = dbs1.Fields("DateApproved").Value

   'Set Insert String'
    InsertStr = "INSERT INTO TrainingList (JobID.[Value]) Values (" & JobIDTbl1 & ") 
    WHERE TrainingID = " & TrainingID & " "

    dbs.Execute InsertStr
    InsertStr2 = "INSERT INTO TrainingList (EmployeeID.[Value]) Values (" &
    EmployeeIDTbl1  & ") 
    WHERE TrainingID = " & TrainingID & " "
    dbs.Execute InsertStr2

'Update Competency And DateApproved'
InsertStr3 = "Update TrainingList SET Competency = '" & CompetencyTbl1 & " ' WHERE   
TrainingID = " & TrainingID & "; "

dbs.Execute InsertStr3
InsertStr4 = "Update TrainingList SET DateApproved = '" & DateApprovedTbl1 & " ' WHERE 
TrainingID = " & TrainingID & "; "

dbs.Execute InsertStr4

    TrainingID = TrainingID + 1
    BuffVal = BuffVal + 1
    dbs1.MoveNext
 Loop


dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Notes About running this code:

The Skeleton of this code runs on this premise

```
INSERT INTO Issues ( AssignedTo.[Value] )
VALUES (6)
WHERE ID = 10;
```

1. Ensure the data in the columns "DO NOT" have null values as it will break it, You can however insert some logic into my code to check for that if you want. What I used it for was good enough.
2. I had a sample database will around 2000 total records to insert, for this smaller scale project It works fine, however it takes quite a bit of time to initialize and insert the records.

Let the script run till it finishes otherwise if you try to use access while it runs it will stop responding. If anyone has a solution to speed up the process of these functions I followed please enlighten me as I am curious.

I really hope this solution will be used as It was frustrating using only certain tools to bypass disabled tools inside SharePoint.

Comment: Could an admin Change the Title of this question to something like "Inserting Records With Multiple Fields With Access and Sharepoint"

Answer (score 0):

Your insert SQL should be:

InsertStr = "INSERT INTO TrainingList (EmployeeID.[Value]) Values(" & EmployeeIDTbl1 & ") Where TrainingID = "  &  TrainingID